# Google Sheets: Dense Ranking from sorted values

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I have a simple table with 3 columns:

[Name] [Score] [Rank]

For the 3rd column, I'm using the following formula to rank each row according to the score:

```
=RANK(C9,$C$9:$C$28,0)
```

The problem is that the formula isn't returning the values I'd expect. For example on the last row it returns 19 when it should be 5.

I found other formulas for ranking (RANK.EQ, etc.) but same issue happens.

Here is the Google Sheet to see it in context:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1P1m7UHPPIcQLQkzpnk-SI1y7-0mhKytCWDjA6FJzFrM/edit?usp=sharing

Any guidance appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @pnuts and @sangboklee for your solutions. I think I have a good solution now. It is pnuts's solution, just simplified:

```
=match(round($C9,0),sort(unique(round($C$9:$C$28,0)),1,false),0)
```

This essentially "embeds" the created array within a single formula, that can be applied to all rows. And as a bonus, the values don't even have to be sorted.

Please check for correctness folks, but I think this works. I've updated the linked Google Sheet from the original question description (it's "Solution 2b").

Comment: Just tried it, looks like the first number is 2? So need to subtract 1 in the formula?

Answer (score 2):

The results you want can be achieved with a simple MATCH formula:

```
=match(round(C9,0),NamedRange1,0)
```

Provided an array (named NamedRange1 for above) is created, say with:

```
=sort(unique(round(C9:C28,0)),1,0)
```

Comment: Thanks - I tried it and I am getting some error (see the linked sheet above in the original question description)....... I think maybe it is due to the array displaying decimals and the rounding of the original range? I'm not sure.....

Comment: I see. I fixed it in the document.

Answer (score 1):

I think the result is as intended. Check this [Ranking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ranking#Standard_competition_ranking_(%221224%22_ranking)) Wikipedia page (called 'standard competition ranking'). It says:

> **Standard competition ranking ("1224" ranking)**
>
> In competition ranking, items that compare equal receive the same
>   ranking number, and then a gap is left in the ranking numbers. The
>   number of ranking numbers that are left out in this gap is one less
>   than the number of items that compared equal. Equivalently, each
>   item's ranking number is 1 plus the number of items ranked above it.
>   This ranking strategy is frequently adopted for competitions, as it
>   means that if two (or more) competitors tie for a position in the
>   ranking, the position of all those ranked below them is unaffected
>   (i.e., a competitor only comes second if exactly one person scores
>   better than them, third if exactly two people score better than them,
>   fourth if exactly three people score better than them, etc.).
>
> Thus if A ranks ahead of B and C (which compare equal) which are both
>   ranked ahead of D, then A gets ranking number 1 ("first"), B gets
>   ranking number 2 ("joint second"), C also gets ranking number 2
>   ("joint second") and D gets ranking number 4 ("fourth").

What you want is 'dense ranking' and it can be achieved by **pnuts**'s answer or something like this:

1. set `G9` to `1`
2. set `G10` to `=if(round(C10,0)<round(C9,0), G9+1, G9)`
3. copy `G10` and paste it into `G11:G28`

Sample sheet is [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PEkVT-fJk0-rKuiB3GSNxSXNE8QTr5MUIBU1_01t6do/).

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about "dense ranking". Yes this is exactly what I want (I am surprised there is no such formula). I see what you did. I am trying pnut's solution but having problems (I added both your and pnuts' solution to my original sheet linked above). I prefer to have the same formula for all rows, if possible. Cheers

Comment: If you prefer one formula, you can set `G9` to `=iferror(if(round(C9,0)<round(C8,0), G8+1, G8),1)` and so on, assuming `C8` is not a value less than `C9`.

Comment: Thanks Sangbok! I fixed it in the document. 
@pnuts Good point - But I do like the fact that your formula doesn't require the list to be sorted. I created a variant of your approach which embeds the array inside a single formula.